# How can C code be run on different processors?

Tags: c, assembly, processor

As I understand it, C code is compiled to machine (assembly) code on someone’s machine, and it becomes an exe file that can be run on lots of different processors (machines). But since different processors have their own unique assembly code how can this code run? Wouldn't the compiled exe only be able to run on one type of processor?

Comment: Many different processor models can be part of the same "family" and share the same machine language.

Comment: It's a bit like the way the same petrol can be used in many, but not all, cars, even though each car has its own engine.

Comment: But can't an exe file can run on all windows machines, even if they have a completely different processor.

Comment: @zappy1333: no. An exe compiled for ARM (mobiles/tablets) won't run on  x86 and vice-versa. I don't know where you got the idea that executables were portable, but that's not the case.

Comment: @Mat But an exe can run on all x86 windows machines, even if they don't have the same processor.

Comment: @zappy1333: no, not all. Mostly backwards compatible, but not forward. If an exe is compiled for a modern CPU, it probably won't run on an i386.

Comment: @Marchill Windows have versions for PowerPC, Alpha, Itanium, ARM... beside x86 and x86_64, so exe for this architecture will not be able to run on Windows on another architecture

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: That is long gone. AFAIK, PPC and Alpha have been dropped with Windows 2000 already, not sure about Itanium (is there a recent Windows for that platform?). And there are binaries which support multiple platforms, see Apple when they moved from 680x0 to PPC then to x86. Also there are CPU/system emulators (again, see Apple, but also Amiga or Atari-Emulators, Bochs, etc.)

Comment: @Olaf of course I know. I mean exe files can contain executables for a lot of Windows architectures. If you found an exe file in an ancient platform it might not run in newer architectures

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Chances are better to run an old exe in a newer Windows than the other way 'round.

Comment: @Olaf yes for the same platform, not if the exe was in ARM and Windows is in x86. So what the OP said "But can't an exe file can run on all windows machines, even if they have a completely different processor." is incorrect

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you compile a program to machine code, you have to select a machine code instruction set, perhaps a mode in which to run the machine (if applicable), and a format in which the resulting code is stored.

All those choices limit the target platform on which the code can be executed.

- The instruction set broadly depends on the type of CPU: x86 ("IBM-compatible"), PowerPC, ARM, MIPS, DEC Alpha, Motorola 68k, ... Within each CPU family, there are many sub-features and generations to choose from (e.g. for x86, there are i386, SSE, AVX, ...). Newer CPUs may be able to execute code limited to older generations, so there may be a common subset.
- The processor mode on x86 depends on the environment: real mode for MS-DOS programs and anything you run on boot-up, protected mode, different addressing modes may be available in some situations (unreal mode)...
- The binary format needs to be recognized by the operating system, or more generally by what ever loading mechanism you have: PE for Windows, ELF for contemporary Linux, a.out in the old days, ... An operating system may provide loaders for multiple binary formats.

This is only the most basic level of platform parameters that you choose when compiling, and your program will only run on platforms that agree on this choice. However, there are many more practical limitations for real-world programs, such as the OS systems interface and the availability of framework libraries, that also need to match. For example, while it's not hard to read and run Windows PE binaries in Linux, the code contained therein doesn't make sense on Linux because it uses Windows-specific software interrupts. However, by intercepting and translating those, it is quite possible to run those binaries on Linux after all.

Comment: Also, (specifically) the PE file format contains a field that explicitly **states** what CPU it is for: "`Machine` The CPU that this file is intended for. The following CPU IDs are defined: ..." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx).

Comment: _"the OS systems interface and the availability of framework libraries, that also need to match"_ I think that's the crucial thing to consider here (for the OP): Even though most computers use an x86 CPU, and they (broadly) speak the same language, it's often the OS that is a decisive factor in the portability of compiled programs. A windows exe can't run on OSX, or linux without some kind of emulator or translator/runtime layer in between (just like Java is compiled to run on a JVM, not directly on the hardware)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Yes. Wine for example intercepts Windows system calls and provides and appropriate implementation on Linux, and ships with the core Windows libraries (implemented for Linux), so that you can run execute a wide variety of Windows programs on Linux. (I imagine it can do the same on MacOS and BSD?)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Exactly. I just commented because I think that this bit of information probably is what the OP actually wanted to know. It explains why/how the same code on the same hardware can be compiled differently for different OS's: for PC's (x86 architecture), the OS is actually the limiting factor, not the actual hardware